# Resetting a variable within subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

If I can increment a variable within a query to append a rank column as such:

```
SET @i = 0;
SELECT *, @i:=@i+1 AS rank FROM table WHERE column="value" ORDER BY time;
```

How can I perform this as a sub-query for all unique `column` values? I believe the real issue is resetting the variable.

Comment: you create a @grp variable, and when it changes (you order by the group thing, like category or whatever, then you increment a 3rd variable perhaps). Often you have a derived table that has a alias

Comment: It would be good if you provide some sample data and expected result so that a better solution could be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to an incremental number for each column (in the fashion of `row_number()` in most other databases), you can still use variables:

```
  SELECT t.*,
         (@i := if(@c = column, @i + 1,
                   if(@c := column, 1, 1)
                  )
         ) as rank
  FROM table t CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT @i := 0, @c := '') params
  ORDER BY column, time;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!